# SSL handshake error (CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED) in grpc++

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, opensuse

I am unable to change find the SSL certificate that the [grpc speech recognition](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cpp-docs-samples) application uses.

I need to change the certificates as I am under a secure network which monitors all the HTTPS traffic and uses a different certificate than default.

While running the above mentioned speech recognition example, I am getting the error as

```
E0128 15:20:51.191576608    7156 ssl_transport_security.cc:1233] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

I tried to find the location where I can change the SSL certificates and put the certificate provided by the *XYZ framework*. I have `XYZ.pem` certificate file which I put in `\etc\ssl\certs` but nothing changed.

Can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: Had the same situation. What is the solution on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem.

Just go to `/etc/ssl/certs` and find where the `ca-bundles.pem` is pointing.

Go to the file `ca-bundles.pem` (for me it was in `/var/lib/ca-certificates/ca-bundles.pem`) and add your certificate manually by copying it from the `.pem` file.

save the changes and run your tests. :)